# Not able to create build because of proguard error

Tags: android, proguard

getting error while implementing proguard. this is what i am using in dependencies.

```
dependencies {


compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.3.0'

}
```

============================================

**BUT GETTING SUCH ERROR.**

> Warning:No SupportedSourceVersion annotation found on me.denley.courier.compiler.DataMapProcessor, returning RELEASE_6.
>
> Warning:Supported source version 'RELEASE_6' from annotation processor 'me.denley.courier.compiler.DataMapProcessor' less than -source '1.7'
>
> Warning:No SupportedSourceVersion annotation found on me.denley.courier.compiler.Processor, returning RELEASE_6.
>
> Warning:Supported source version 'RELEASE_6' from annotation processor 'me.denley.courier.compiler.Processor' less than -source '1.7'
>
> Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
>
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
>
> 4 warnings

---

**EXCEPTION FROM SIMULATION:**

> com.android.dx.rop.cst.CstMethodRef cannot be cast to com.android.dx.rop.cst.CstInterfaceMethodRef
>
> stack[top0]: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/q;**   (I think , issue is in play service but what?)

List item

> 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin\java.exe'' finished    with non-zero exit value 1

---

I googled and found that such error can be occurred because of old play service 7.5.0. So, i have updated play service 8.3.0. but still getting same error.

please help me out to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but it looks to me like you might be dealing with multiple problems, one of which is an issue with ProGuard obfuscation and Play Services 8.x, detailed here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=187483